# Comparing values of parts of two tuples in python

Tags: python, tuples

Here is a simple code I have:

```
a=(6,3,4,5)
b=(1,2,1,3)

if (a[i]<b[i+1]  for i in range(1,3)):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

what I am trying to do is 
print Yes if a[1] < b[2] and a[2] < a[3], otherwise return No.

This code always returns Yes. Any hint on how to modify this?

Comment: Is your sentence "what I am ... a[1]" unfinished?

Comment: Did you mean `a[1] < b[2] and a[2] < a[3]` or `a[1] < b[2] and a[2] < b[3]`? i.e. did you mean for the second  comparison to be on members of the same tuple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `all` or `any` to test all values in a tuple simultaneously. `all` returns `True` if everything in the iterable is `True`-ish; `any` returns `True` if anything in the iterable is `True`-ish.

For example:

```
if all(a[i]<b[i+1]  for i in range(1,3)):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I do not want to compare all elements. As you can see, I skipped the first element of b and last element of a.

Comment: @NNsr: You can specify an arbitrary iterable - for example, just the comparisons you made above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) to accumulate the results:

```
def test(a, b):
    return "Yes" if (reduce(lambda i, j: a[i]<b[j], range(1,3))) else "No"


a=(6,3,4,5)
b=(1,2,1,3)
print test(a, b) # "No"

a=(0,0,0,0)
print test(a, b) # "Yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `zip()`, which acts like a zipper  - give it two sequences and it meshes them together, giving the first element of each, the second element of each, etc.:

```
>>> a=(6,3,4,5)
>>> b=(1,2,1,3)
>>> list(zip(a,b))
[(6, 1), (3, 2), (4, 1), (5, 3)]
```

Then you could slice that to the ones you are interested in:

```
>>> zip(a,b)[1:3]
[(3, 2), (4, 1)]
```

Then test those in a loop:

```
for an, bn in zip(a, b)[1:3]:
    if an < bn:
      ???
```

And use [Python's `for/else` loop thing](http://psung.blogspot.co.uk/2007/12/for-else-in-python.html) to handle tracking all of them while only printing the output once. Fail and print No as soon as one is wrong, and if it gets to the end and none are wrong, print Yes.

```
for an, bn in zip(a, b)[1:3]:
    if an > bn:
        print("No")
        break
else:
    print("Yes")
```

Comment: Thank you. But in this way you compare ith element of one tuple with ith element of the other one. I am interested in comparing ith element of one with (i+1)th element of the other one.

Comment: I prefer @nneonneo's answer, I hadn't seen it at the time I was writing mine. But within my answer, there's no reason you need to `zip(a, b)`, you could `zip(a, b[1:])` to have an offset.